# Google Drive Upload Image - Data not returning webContentLink - Direct permenant link

Tags: google-drive-api

I am uploading an image to the API successfully like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;  boundary="' + boundary + '"'
--data: multipartRequestBody
```

Where `multipartRequestBody` is:

```
{
    name: 'screenshot.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    // parents: ['0B5IwavgVGMN9ekR2dEhuaUxkZTA'] // set this to the id of a the folder you want to upload it into
};
```

Is there some keys I can provide to my `mulitpartRequestBody` that will tell GDrive to upload this as a publicly shared file and return the `webContentLink`? Which I can use in `src` of `<img src="...">` with no restrictions on view bandwidth?

I have tried setting `writersCanShare: true` however it still won't return a `webContentLink`. I have also tried adding `type: 'anyone', role: 'reader'` but that didn't work either.

Basically I am trying to do what `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileId}` does, but within the `insert` call to the API.

Thanks

Comment: webContentLink can be accessed once the Files resource were retrieve (ie, using `get`). Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#viewing_files_in_a_browser, it doesn't need authorization once you've specified it. `insert` should be able to have `webContentLink` as well since it also uses Files resources for its response. There are other ways to download files, but I don't think those fit on your intended case.

Comment: @adjuremods thanks for the input I experiemented and I had to first upuload with `files.insert`, then  set permission for `role=reader,type=anyone,withLink=true` for that id with `permissions.insert`, then I had to fetch meta data for the file with `files` with request for field `webContentLink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer to all your requirements is no.**

Drive is not designed to be a free public hosting service, but rather sharing/viewing/editing of content between people. You will run in to things like bandwidth limitations, abuse detection, etc if you really are trying to use it in a manner that requires "no restrictions on view bandwidth".

The other main part is you will have to do a `files.get` request from the id returned in the `files.insert` call - you will not be able to do it in a single API call on just the insert.

You would be much better served by using [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) which has a [REST/JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) similar to what you are using with Drive.

Comment: Thanks Dan for that idea on google cloud storage! For now I hooked up google drive like you said - I had to first upuload with `files.insert`, then  set permission for `role=reader,type=anyone,withLink=true` for that id with `permissions.insert`, then I had to fetch meta data for the file with `files` with request for field `webContentLink`. Does this sound correct? It works is all I know haha. The bandwidth issue sucks, do you know the limits on that? I'll add in google cloud option as well. :) edit: ah google cloud storage is not free is it?